# Perl DBI: get array of columns that are in index foo of table bar

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

I have an array with columns that should be fulltext-indexed:

```
my @cols = ('col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3');
```

I also have a corresponding and already connected dbi…:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(…);
```

… that contains a table *bar* with a fulltext-index *foo*.

As I can't modify an existing index' columns, I have to drop it and recreate it if array `@cols` differs in elements from the **array of columns that are in index *foo* of table *bar***, which is exactly what I don't know how to get.

Does anyone know how to get that?

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: MySQL, but as DBI is an abstraction-layer, it *should* be its purpose to make that irrelevant as long as the engine supports a feature.

Answer (score 0):

The short version is to use [`DBI`'s `statistics_info` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#statistics_info), which seems now to be widely implemented across `DBD`s:

```
my $table = 'bar';
my $index = 'foo';
my @applicable_columns;
# $dbh already defined
my $schema = undef;
my $catalog = undef;
my $sth = $dbh->statistics_info( $catalog, $schema, $table, undef, 1 );
$sth->execute;
while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
    next unless $row->{INDEX_NAME} eq $index;
    $applicable_columns[$row->{ORDINAL_POSITION}] = $row->{COLUMN_NAME};
}
$sth->finish;
shift @applicable_columns; # since starts from 1, index 0 will be undef
```

The above code has been partly cribbed from [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::DBI](https://metacpan.org/source/ILMARI/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07049/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader/DBI.pm).

A prospective plug: work is ongoing to take code from the `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::DBI` subclasses to properly implement the `SQL::Translator::Parser::DBI` subclasses (and then make `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` use the resulting `SQL::Translator::Schema`), which will then also offer good generic code to answer this sort of question.